# Adding custom graph attributes

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to add a custom graph attribute to an igraph object. I use the code

```
graph = set_graph_attr(graph, "directed", FALSE)
data_json <- d3_igraph(igraph)
write(data_json, "graph.json")
```

and the output appears as

```json
{
  "nodes" [
     {
        "name": "something"
     },
     {
        "name": "something_else"
     }
  ],
  "links": [
      {
         "source": "something",
         "target": "something_else"
      }
   ],
  "attributes": {
      "directed": false
  }
}
```

The added attribute goes into an `attributes` section of the json, but what I would really like to output is:

```json
{
  "nodes" [
     {
        "name": "something"
     },
     {
        "name": "something_else"
     }
  ],
  "links": [
      {
         "source": "something",
         "target": "something_else"
      }
   ],
  "attributes": {
  },
  "directed": false
}
```

where the new attribute is added at the top level of the json rather than in the `attributes` section. Is that possible? Eventually the plan is to add several custom attributes including metadata with a more complex structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example isn't fully reproducible, but the development version of the CRAN package [rjsoncons](https://mtmorgan.github.io/rjsoncons) has `j_patch_apply()`, which allows one to 'patch' a JSON document as illustrated at the [JSON patch](https://jsonpatch.com) web site. So after

```
remotes::install_github(mtmorgan/rjsoncons)
```

one should be able to do something like

```
json <- d3_igraph(igraph)
patch <- '[{"op": "move", "from": "/attributes/directed", "path": "/directed"}]'
json_patched <- j_patch_apply(json, patch)
```

Comment: This looks like a great package and much easier than writing a function to replicate `d3r::d3_igraph()` and a bunch of tests to make sure the output is the same!

Comment: Really simple to use and allows me to add directly rather than always have to move from already added attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The [source](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/d3r/blob/e824baa8a01fdc3492ee287d734ebb5c120f893c/R/igraph.R#L47) for `d3r::d3_igraph()` hard codes attributes into their own section of the json on line 47. So it doesn't seem possible to do it using that function. However, the approach of `d3r` is to convert the graph to a data frame, rename the columns to the keys `d3.js` expects and then send it off to `jsonlite`. This can be replicated fairly easily with the additional feature of putting attributes at the top level.

```r
generate_d3_json <- function(g, numeric_index = FALSE, attrs_to_keep = "directed") {
    # Convert to data frame like d3r
    d <- igraph::as_data_frame(g, what = "both")
    d$vertices$id <- rownames(d$vertices)

    # zero-indexing so we can compare output to d3r
    if (numeric_index) {
        d <- lapply(d, \(dat) {
            nm <- intersect(c("from", "to", "id"), names(dat))
            dat[nm] <- lapply(dat[nm], \(x) as.character(as.integer(x) - 1))
            dat
        })
    }

    l <- c(
        list(
            nodes = d$vertices,
            links = setNames(d$edges, c("source", "target", tail(names(d$edges), -2)))
        ),
        igraph::graph_attr(g)[attrs_to_keep]
    )
    jsonlite::toJSON(l, auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)
}
```

You can choose which top-level attributes to keep with the `attrs_to_keep` parameter. If your vertices are identified by numbers then set `numeric_index` to `TRUE`. I've set the default to `FALSE` as in your example they're named. The function will return a json in the desired format.

### Graphs with named vertices

```r
g <- igraphdata::Koenigsberg |>
    igraph::set_graph_attr("directed", FALSE)

generate_d3_json(g)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "name": "Altstadt-Loebenicht",
      "Euler_letter": "B",
      "id": "Altstadt-Loebenicht",
      "_row": "Altstadt-Loebenicht"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kneiphof",
      "Euler_letter": "A",
      "id": "Kneiphof",
      "_row": "Kneiphof"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vorstadt-Haberberg",
      "Euler_letter": "C",
      "id": "Vorstadt-Haberberg",
      "_row": "Vorstadt-Haberberg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Lomse",
      "Euler_letter": "D",
      "id": "Lomse",
      "_row": "Lomse"
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "source": "Altstadt-Loebenicht",
      "target": "Kneiphof",
      "Euler_letter": "a",
      "name": "Kraemer Bruecke"
    },
    {
      "source": "Altstadt-Loebenicht",
      "target": "Kneiphof",
      "Euler_letter": "b",
      "name": "Schmiedebruecke"
    },
    {
      "source": "Altstadt-Loebenicht",
      "target": "Lomse",
      "Euler_letter": "f",
      "name": "Holzbruecke"
    },
    {
      "source": "Kneiphof",
      "target": "Lomse",
      "Euler_letter": "e",
      "name": "Honigbruecke"
    },
    {
      "source": "Vorstadt-Haberberg",
      "target": "Lomse",
      "Euler_letter": "g",
      "name": "Hohe Bruecke"
    },
    {
      "source": "Kneiphof",
      "target": "Vorstadt-Haberberg",
      "Euler_letter": "c",
      "name": "Gruene Bruecke"
    },
    {
      "source": "Kneiphof",
      "target": "Vorstadt-Haberberg",
      "Euler_letter": "d",
      "name": "Koettelbruecke"
    }
  ],
  "directed": false
}
```

We can check this worked:

```r
d3r_output <- jsonlite::fromJSON(d3r::d3_igraph(g))
my_d3_output <- jsonlite::fromJSON(generate_d3_json(g))

common_names <- intersect(names(d3r_output), names(my_d3_output))
# ^^ c("nodes", "links")

identical(
    d3r_output[common_names],
    my_d3_output[common_names]
)
# [1] TRUE
```

### Graphs without named nodes

If you have nodes without names then set `numeric_index = TRUE`. This is not actually necessary but it will zero-index meaning we can easily compare with the `d3r` output:

```r
g <- igraph::make_ring(3) |>
    igraph::set_graph_attr("directed", FALSE)

generate_d3_json(g, numeric_index = TRUE)
# ^^ produces the json output
```

Again, we can check that this gives the same output as `d3r`:

```r
d3r_output <- jsonlite::fromJSON(d3r::d3_igraph(g))
my_d3_output <- jsonlite::fromJSON(generate_d3_json(g, numeric_index = TRUE))
identical(d3r_output[common_names], my_d3_output[common_names]) # TRUE
```